# Sum the properties of array of object types and join them as single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

Need to sum the `score` and `total_score` of distinct objects based on subject names property.

Input data :

```
var data = [{
  name: "One",
  maths: {
    score: 2,
    total_score: 4
  },
  science: {
    score: 2,
    total_score: 4
  },
  social: {
    score: 2,
    total_score: 4
  }
}, {
  name: "One",
  maths: {
    score: 3,
    total_score: 4
  },
  science: {
    score: 1,
    total_score: 4
  },
  english: {
    score: 4,
    total_score: 4
  }
}]
```

Expected Output :

```
{
  name: "One",
  maths: {
    score: 5,
    total_score: 8
  },
  science: {
    score: 3,
    total_score: 8
  },
  social: {
    score: 2,
    total_score: 4
  },
  english: {
    score: 4,
    total_score: 4
  }
}
```

I have tried this :

```
data.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.name]) {
        this[a.name] = { name: a.name, contributions: 0 };
        result.push(this[a.name]);
    }
    this[a.name].contributions += a.contributions;
}, Object.create(null));
```

But it does not work for my case. Where the `contributions` object is different i.e Subject names are different each time.

Thanks in advance folks!

Comment: Please use the 'name' property to compare each object in array

Comment: Hi! When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful info in it. There was also a toolbar full of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area showing what your post would look like when posted, located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it). Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: (I've fixed the formatting for you on this occasion.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder any hope for answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try following

- Convert the array into an object using **Array.reduce** with key as name and value as resulting object. And then use **Object.values** to collect all the values from the created object
- While creating object, check if key (name) exists in object. If not, add an entry for it (`a[name] = a[name] || {name};`).
- Now for all the other keys (**subjects**), create an array using **Object.entries** and iterate over it to add/update the values of score and total_score.

```js
var data = [{name: "One", maths: {score: 2, total_score: 4}, science: {score: 2, total_score: 4}, social: {score: 2, total_score: 4}},{name: "One", maths: {score: 3, total_score: 4}, science: {score: 1, total_score: 4}, english: {score: 4, total_score: 4}}];
var result = Object.values(data.reduce((a,{name, ...rest}) => {
  a[name] = a[name] || {name};
  Object.entries(rest).forEach(([k,v]) => {
    a[name][k] = a[name][k] || {score:0, total_score:0};
    a[name][k].score += v.score;
    a[name][k].total_score += v.total_score;
  });
  return a;
},{}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what i want :)

Comment: @PrazSolver - Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce()`:

```js
var data = [{
    name: "One",
    maths: {
      score: 2,
      total_score: 4
    },
    science: {
      score: 2,
      total_score: 4
    },
    social: {
      score: 2,
      total_score: 4
    }
  },
  {
    name: "One",
    maths: {
      score: 3,
      total_score: 4
    },
    science: {
      score: 1,
      total_score: 4
    },
    english: {
      score: 4,
      total_score: 4
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Two",
    maths: {
      score: 3,
      total_score: 4
    },
    science: {
      score: 1,
      total_score: 4
    },
    english: {
      score: 4,
      total_score: 4
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Two",
    maths: {
      score: 3,
      total_score: 5
    },
    science: {
      score: 1,
      total_score: 5
    },
    english: {
      score: 4,
      total_score: 6
    }
  }
];
var res = data.reduce((acc, item)=>{
  var exist = acc.find(({name}) => name === item.name);
  if(exist){
    Object.keys(item).forEach((key) =>{
      if(key !== 'name'){
        if(exist[key]){
          exist[key].total_score += item[key].total_score;
          exist[key].score += item[key].score
        } else {
           exist[key] = item[key]
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    acc.push(item);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array as temporary result for reducing and look for the object with the same name and update all futher properties.

```js
var data = [{ name: "One", maths: { score: 2, total_score: 4 }, science: { score: 2, total_score: 4 }, social: { score: 2, total_score: 4 } }, { name: "One", maths: { score: 3, total_score: 4 }, science: { score: 1, total_score: 4 }, english: { score: 4, total_score: 4 } }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        var temp = r.find(({ name }) => name === o.name);
        if (!temp) {
            r.push(temp = { name: o.name });
        }
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, p]) => {
            if (k === 'name') return;
            temp[k] = temp[k] || {};
            ['score', 'total_score'].forEach(l => temp[k][l] = (temp[k][l] || 0) + o[k][l]);
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```